# What's the best way to get the UTC offset in Perl?

Tags: perl, formatting, timestamp

I need to get the UTC offset of the current time zone in Perl in a cross platform (Windows and various flavors of Unix) way.  It should meet this format:

> zzzzzz, which represents ±hh:mm in relation to UTC

It looks like I should be able to get it via `strftime()`, but it doesn't appear to be consistent.

Unix:

```
Input: perl -MPOSIX -e "print strftime(\"%z\", localtime());"
Output: -0700
```

Windows:

```
Input: perl -MPOSIX -e "print strftime(\"%z\", localtime());"
Output: Mountain Standard Time
```

While it appears that Unix is giving me what I want (or at least something close), Windows is not.  I'm pretty sure I can do it with `Date::Time` or similar, but I'd really like to not have any dependencies that I can't guarantee a user will have due to our wide install base.

Am I missing something obvious here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Time::Local` should do the trick

```
use Time::Local;
@t = localtime(time);
$gmt_offset_in_seconds = timegm(@t) - timelocal(@t);
```

Comment: `Time::Local` is a core module in all Perl 5 distributions.

Comment: This is a great solution; only gave it a rudimentary test, but it seems to work just as it should.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a portable solution using only the core POSIX module:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'my $tz = (localtime time)[8] * 60 - mktime(gmtime 0) / 60; printf "%+03d:%02d\n", $tz / 60, abs($tz) % 60;'
```

---

**Bonus:** The following subroutine will return a full timestamp with time zone offset and microseconds, as in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.nnnnnn [+-]HHMM":

```
use POSIX qw[mktime strftime];
use Time::HiRes qw[gettimeofday];

sub timestamp () {
  my @now = gettimeofday;
  my $tz  = (localtime $now[0])[8] * 60 - mktime(gmtime 0) / 60;
  my $ts  = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime $now[0]);
  return sprintf "%s.%06d %+03d%02d", $ts, $now[1], $tz / 60, abs($tz) % 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the difference between [`localtime($t)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) and [`gmtime($t)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html). Here is my version inspired by [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143528/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-utc-offset-in-perl/2143586#2143586):

```
use strict;
use warnings;    

sub tz_offset
{
    my $t = shift;
    my @l = localtime($t);
    my @g = gmtime($t);

    my $minutes = ($l[2] - $g[2] + ((($l[5]<<9)|$l[7]) <=> (($g[5]<<9)|$g[7])) * 24) * 60 + $l[1] - $g[1];
    return $minutes unless wantarray;
    return (int($minutes / 60), $minutes % 60);
}

push @ARGV, time;
foreach my $t (@ARGV) {
    printf "%s (%d): %+03d%02u\n", scalar localtime($t), $t, tz_offset($t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `Time::Piece` like below, docs [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time::Piece)

```
my $offsetinsecs = localtime(time)->tzoffset;
my $datetimetz = sprintf("%+2d:%02d", $datetimetz, $offsetinsecs/3600, abs($offsetinsecs/60%60));
```

One way to manually test is by changing the tz

```
use POSIX qw(tzset);
$ENV{TZ} = 'America/Los_Angeles';
```

related stackoverflow anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396873/11337921

Answer (score -2):

A portable way is to compare the output of `localtime` with `gmtime`

```
    $t = time;
    @a = localtime($t);
    @b = gmtime($t);

    $hh = $a[2] - $b[2];
    $mm = $a[1] - $b[1];
    # in the unlikely event that localtime and gmtime are in different years
    if ($a[5]*366+$a[4]*31+$a[3] > $b[5]*366+$b[4]*31+$b[3]) {
      $hh += 24;
    } elsif ($a[5]*366+$a[4]*31+$a[3] < $b[5]*366+$b[4]*31+$b[3]) {
      $hh -= 24;
    }
    if ($hh < 0 && $mm > 0) {
      $hh++;
      $mm = 60-$mm;
    }
    printf "%+03d:%02d\n", $hh, $mm;
```

Someone pointing out that this is already implemented in a module somewhere in 5, 4, 3, ...

Comment: Can you explain the calculation in the if statment -- why multiply the year by the number of days in a leap year? why Month * 31? Why add the day?  Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin Friedman - it is a test to see if `@a[5,4,3]` and `@b[5,4,3]` represent the same day. I combine year, month, and day into a single number so I can get by with one comparison instead of three. You could use larger numbers than 366 and 31 and you would still get the right result.

Comment: You should use bit fields instead of multiplication if you want to be fast: `($a[5]<<13)|($a[4]<<5)|$a[3]`. Also, the `<=>` operator that could be used to replace the if statement.

Comment: Even faster: `($a[5]<<9)|$a[7]` (`$a[7]` is the day number in the year)