# How can I change the timezone of a datetime value in Perl?

Tags: perl, timezone, solaris, epoch

Using this function:

```
perl -e 'use Time::Local; print timelocal("00","00","00","01","01","2000"),"\n";'
```

It will return an epochtime - but only in GMT - if i want the result in GMT+1 (which is the systems localtime(TZ)), what do i need to change?

Thanks in advance,

Anders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one standard definition for epochtime, based on UTC, and not different epochtimes for different timezones.

If you want to find the [offset between gmtime and localtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143528/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-utc-offset-in-perl/2143609#2143609), use

```
use Time::Local;
@t = localtime(time);
$gmt_offset_in_seconds = timegm(@t) - timelocal(@t);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
use DateTime;
my $dt   = DateTime->now;
$dt->set_time_zone( 'Europe/Madrid' );
```

Comment: Very clean answer.  Here's a list of TimeZones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 3):

While Time::Local is a reasonable solution, you may be better off using the more modern DateTime object oriented module. Here's an example:

```
use strict;
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now;
print $dt->epoch, "\n";
```

For the timezones, you can use the DateTime::TimeZone module.

```
use strict;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

my $dt = DateTime->now;
my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => "local");

$dt->add(seconds => $tz->offset_for_datetime($dt));

print $dt->epoch, "\n";
```

CPAN Links:

[DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

Answer (score 3):

An other example based on [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime)

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $s = "2016-12-22T06:16:29.798Z";
my $p = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%T.%NZ",
  time_zone => "UTC"
);

my $dt = $p->parse_datetime($s);    
$dt->set_time_zone("Europe/Berlin");
say join ' ', $dt->ymd, $dt->hms; # shows 2016-12-22 07:16:29
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the timezone.  Try:

```
env TZ=UTC+1 perl -e 'use Time::Local; print timelocal("00","00","00","01","01","2000"),"\n";'
```

Comment: TLA timezones are ambiguous and poorly defined. It is better to use [zoneinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olson_database) names: `TZ=Europe/Berlin perl ...`

Comment: Here is a link directly to the [list of valid Time Zone strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) aka `Zone.tab`.

Answer (score 2):

`Time::Local::timelocal` is the inverse of `localtime`. The result will be in your host's local time:

```
$ perl -MTime::Local -le \
    'print scalar localtime timelocal "00","00","00","01","01","2000"'
Tue Feb  1 00:00:00 2000
```

Do you want the `gmtime` that corresponds to that `localtime`?

```
$ perl -MTime::Local' -le \
    'print scalar gmtime timelocal "00","00","00","01","01","2000"'
Mon Jan 31 23:00:00 2000
```

Do you want it the other way around, the `localtime` that corresponds to that `gmtime`?

```
$ perl -MTime::Local -le \
    'print scalar localtime timegm "00","00","00","01","01","2000"'
Tue Feb  1 01:00:00 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The Algorithm

If you want to change a time value from one timezone to another timezone, you must be able to ***indicate both timezones.***

After all, if you set if you want to convert `"12:30"` to GMT or US/Eastern or Venezuelan time, which means adding/subtracting some amount of hours or hours and minutes, you need to know what timezone *is the starting time zone,* otherwise, the calculation won't know how much to add or subtract.

*If you use `DateTime->now;`, the timezone is defaulted to the system-time, which may not be the timezone you want to convert from.*

In the below code, I demonstrate how to initialize the datetime object to the right starting timezone (`fromtimezone`) and how to convert that time to the ending timezone (`totimezone`)...

#### Working Code

I could not find a Perl sandbox online with the `DateTime` CPAN module installed.

```
use strict;
use DateTime;

sub convertTimeZonesForTime {
        my ($args) = @_;

        my $time = $args->{time};
        my $date = $args->{date};
        my $totimezone = $args->{totimezone};
        my $fromtimezone = $args->{fromtimezone};
        my $format = $args->{format} || '%H:%M:%S';

        my ($year, $month, $day) = map {int $_} split('-', $date);
        my ($hour, $minute, $second) = map {int $_} split(':', $time);

        $year ||= 1999 if !defined $year;
        $month ||= 1 if !defined $month;
        $day ||= 1 if !defined $day;
        $hour ||= 12 if !defined $hour;
        $minute ||= 30 if !defined $minute;
        $second ||= 0 if !defined $second;

        my $dt = DateTime->new(
                year=>$year,
                month=>$month,
                day=>$day,
                hour=>$hour,
                minute=>$minute,
                second=>$second,
                time_zone => $fromtimezone,
        );
        my $formatter = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(pattern => $format);
        $dt->set_formatter($formatter);
        $dt->set_time_zone($totimezone);

        return "$dt";
}

print(convertTimeZonesForTime({
    'totimezone'=>'America/Denver',
    'fromtimezone'=>'US/Eastern',
    'time'=>'12:30:00',
}));
```

Output:

> 10:30:00